# authentication file sharing with qr code

Tags: authentication

I want to share a file for viewing purposes to customers. The qr code will be imprinted on the product, so the customer will be the only one with access to it. The file should not be accessible to anyone else, except for the holder of the qr code.

How can I make the server realize, whether the request for the file came by scanning said qr code or whether the url has been guessed or been made public? Any way to add some authentication to the qr code? Only possibilities I can think of are passwording or making the url long to prevent bruteforce.. First one kinda defeats the purpose of qr codes and latter one isn't really safe, since there are still many ways, the url could be compromised..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QR codes are just encoding of text. There is nothing to embed. The QR code is simply a representation of an URL, in your case. There is nothing about the QR code that you can use as a control, so you need to think beyond that.

To do what you want, it would appear to be better to simply display a password in the file that the user enters once they use the QR code. The challenge here is to maintain passwords. You *could* use the same password (or a small set) for each file to reduce your programming complexity, if you're ok with the possibility of someone with a file trying to brute-force URLs and trying passwords.

The purpose of QR codes is to make URLs easier to access. That's all. Adding a simple field to ask for a password does not violate the purpose of QR codes.

Alternatively, because QR codes are most often scanned with phones, then your server could inspect the user-agent of the client connecting to determine if it is a phone or not, which *might* filter out unwanted automated requests. This is a weak control since anyone who understands your protection mechanism could also change their user-agent to one that looks like a phone.

Comment: Can I mayhaps realize this with certificates? Like creating a mixed qr code with certificate as plaintext and url... Then again the qr reader still needs to be able to interpret this.. And this seems much more cumbersome than a simple password.

Comment: @Tomatwo a QR code is just a image. It's trivial to copy it. I can take a photo and send it to someone at the other side of the planet and there is no way for you to find out it I did take the photo or she did. In short: Not possible!

Comment: @Tomatwo "mixed QR code" -- basically no such thing. You're just creating a very long URL.

Comment: Meaning if I wanted any kind of meaningful security it would have to happen either serverside (e.g. login prompt) or directly on the file? I thought I might have been overseeing obvious solutions, since I am not very knowledgeable in this field..

Comment: Consider the QR just like a URL. There is literally no difference. It's just super fast for the user to enter. So, whatever you can do with a URL, you can do with a QR code, and no more.

Comment: I for my part don't know any method to transmit sensitve information with an url. But is there any method? I mean anything I am sending to the server has to be in the url and will be logged and saved by server and browser.. Encrypted or plaintext, in my eyes there is no logical way to transmit sensitive data, since anyone could just copy and paste..

Comment: There isn't a way.